# Davies' definition of elliptic operators in "Heat Kernels and Spectral Theory"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, heat-equation

I am trying to find my way through Davies' book, and one of the difficult points is his choice of what "elliptic operator" means in his text. This is the first time that I encounter some of the concepts in the text, so I apologize if something below if wrong (any mistake is mine, not Davies').

One begins with a *smooth* matrix function $x \mapsto(a_{ij} (x))$ (Davies takes it to be measurable, but I don't need this) that is positive-definite and symmetric, from which one constructs the quadratic form

$$Q(f) = \int \limits _U \sum _{i,j} a_{ij} \frac {\partial f} {\partial x_i} \frac {\partial \bar f} {\partial x_j}$$

for $f \in C_c ^\infty (U)$ (the smooth compactly-supported functions on the open subset $U \subset \mathbb R^n$).

Assume that $\lambda > 0$ is a continuous function on $U$ and that $a > \lambda$ (i.e. $a - \lambda I_n$ is a positive-definite matrix function). Theorem 1.2.6 guarantees that $Q$ is closable on $f \in C_c ^\infty (U)$, therefore, according to theorem 1.2.1, there exists a self-adjoint operator $H \ge 0$ such that

$$Q(f) = \begin{cases}
\langle \sqrt H f, \sqrt H f \rangle, & f \in \operatorname{Dom} \sqrt H \cap \overline{ C_c ^\infty (U) } \\
\infty, & f \in \overline{ C_c ^\infty (U) } \setminus \operatorname{Dom} \sqrt H \end{cases}$$

where the closure is taken in $L^2(U)$.

*Such an operator $H$ is called "elliptic" by Davies.*

Davies next notes that if $U$ has smooth boundary then

$$H = - \sum _{i,j} \frac \partial {\partial x_i} \left( a_{ij} \frac {\partial f} {\partial x_j} \right) \ .$$

> 1. Why does Davies leave the "other" elliptic operators out?
> 2. Should I understand that the Gaussian bounds for the integral kernel of $\mathrm e ^{tH}$ do not hold for general 2nd order elliptic operators, or has the theory been improved since then?
> 3. The reason why I am asking is that, in a system of coordinates, the Laplace operator of a Riemannian manifold does not have the form required by Davies, which I find *really* strange, because this is one of the most important operators on a manifold and it is disappointing to see that Davies' theory does not hold in this simple and important case.

Comment: What do you mean by "other elliptic operators"? (I know that some other text define an abstract version of ellipticity in terms of sending $H^{ṣ+2}$ onto $H^{s}$)

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez: Take a look at [the general definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_operator#Definitions) and notice that Davies' one is more restrictive. In particular (to give a stupid trivial example) $-\Delta$ is elliptic according to Davies, but $-\Delta + 1$ is not.

Comment: The Laplacian does have the form required by Davies. The expression for the Euclidean Laplacian you have in mind is given by setting $a_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$. This reduces then to show that form of your $H$ will be $H=-\sum_{i}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}$.

Comment: @HadrianQuan: I am asking about the Laplacian on Riemannian manifolds, expressed in local coordinates. I do not understand your comment.

Comment: Hi @AlexM., the portion of Davies you've quoted is defining an elliptic differential operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you'd like to define such an operator on a general manifold then the definition is given a bit differently. 

In particular, to respond to your question 3), the expression for the Laplacian on a Riemannian manifold does reduce to the definition given by Davies on $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is $$\Delta_g=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{det(g)}}\sum_{i,j}\partial_i(g^{ij}\sqrt{det(g)}\partial_j)$$. Since the Euclidean metric has $g_{ij}:=\delta_{ij}$, and $det(g_{ij})=1$, this reduces to your equation.

Comment: @HadrianQuan: But why do you keep talking about the "Euclidean" case? I am asking about the purely Riemannian one, where the extra factor $\frac 1 {\sqrt {\det g}}$ in front of the sum spoils everything.

Comment: @AlexM., Davies defines elliptic differential operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The portion you've quoted does not attempt to say anything more generally about Riemannian manifolds. Referring to Euclidean case, I'm just trying to highlight that for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with it's standard metric the formulas you are quoting simplify to Davies'.


I'm saying all of this because I'm not sure what you're asking in your question 3. "In a system of coordinates, the Laplace operator of a Riemannian manifold does not have the form required by Davies", because he's not defined anything that generally yet.

Comment: One more thing to note: $-\Delta+1$ is an elliptic operator, even by the definition you've quoted from wiki. Ellipticity typically refers to a condition imposed on the highest order derivatives of your differential operator. In particular, altering an elliptic operator (like $-\Delta$) by some term of lower order in its number of derivatives (like 1), remains elliptic ($-\Delta+1$).